# Start the Activity After Multiple Permission?android 6+

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I have Given this to Req Multiple permission at my splash screen

```
public class Main_MulPer extends Activity {

public static final int R_PERM = 321;

Context context = this;

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rcssa);


    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
    Manifest.permission.NFC,
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,     
    };

    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);

        Main_MulPer.this.finish();
        Intent ss = new Intent(Main_MulPer.this, Main_acti.class);
        ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(ss);

    } else {
        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) ;
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Main_MulPer.this.finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Main_MulPer.this, Splash_two.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }, 3000);

        }
    }

}

}
```

So here My problem is that Its Asking two Permission at a time...

If I try to grant them its moving to another Activity... So I have Given Similar 3 activities with 2 Permission on Each..

But Due to Handler its Opening new activities..
Then I removed Delay Handler... Now It opening Last activity... Directly...

Can Any one Suggest Me How to Start The Main Activity after All Permissions only...
Without permission It should Exit app... Please Help me on this

**Update**

Insted of Multiple permissions I have Splited the 3 activities with two permission each... But here It should Go to next activity after permission But its Going to last activity every time first two activity permission are missing
So I need to exit app and give them...

**All I need is that without permission don't move to next screen**

Can any one suggest me after permission only move to next activity....

Comment: This is a very bad approach, you should only ask for permissions when it is very obvious to the user why you need them (ie. they click on a camera, it asks for camera permission), doing anything otherwise is not advised.

Also, just as an after thought you should never batch ask for permissions just because one wasn't granted, as denying a permission that was previously granted will automatically kill the application in question

Comment: But My app Is Commercial So I have Given All at once.... Because when once user logins in its will run almost 24hs... So asking every time is very burden... If I give Every time its a Bad approach....

Comment: It does not matter whether it is commercial or not, that has absolutely nothing to do with it. It will not ask every time, i very much suggest you properly read the documentation surrounding permissions, because it does not ask the user every time, only if they haven't already granted permission

Comment: "If I give Every time its a Bad approach"..Totally disagree with this.. Idea behind Run time permissions is to give users the eligibility to install without granting all the permissions at installation time itself. Only when the user needs a specific feature, we need to ask for permission. Actually you should ask every time(means check user has permission to access a feature). If you don't check for that & permission is manually disabled by user, your app will crash in 6.0+.

Comment: In my activity I have a lot of things to ask permissions... I dont know which comes first ... So I have given like this,,, If possible  Answer in this way... I dont choose other way,.,, Because this app runs fine in android 5 but due to runtime permissions its not wokring So client dont accept it...

Comment: At least try and post code where you are _correctly_ asking for permission, asking for permission and then just blatantly assuming they accept within 3 seconds is not in anyway correct.

I mean even those two if statements are the same `if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS))` followed by `else if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS))` ...

Comment: @Joe Maher In that its going to some other activity in If and else if its going to some other activity...  please check complete code,....I am not criticising you I am just taking correct answer... if every one follow your point without checking question I dont get answer.. Thats why I said.... if any thing wrong on me excuse me... please\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
 public class Main_nPRC extends Activity {

public static final String MainPP_SP = "MainPP_data";
public static final int R_PERM = 2822;
private static final int REQUEST= 112;

Context mContext = this;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rcssa);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MainPP_SP, 0);
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) settings.getAll();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        Log.d("TAG","@@@ IN IF Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23");
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                android. Manifest.permission.NFC,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        };


        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
            Log.d("TAG","@@@ IN IF hasPermissions");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG","@@@ IN ELSE hasPermissions");
            callNextActivity();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG","@@@ IN ELSE  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23");
        callNextActivity();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("TAG","@@@ PERMISSIONS grant");
                callNextActivity();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG","@@@ PERMISSIONS Denied");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "PERMISSIONS Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void callNextActivity()
{
    Intent ss = new Intent(Main_nPRC.this, NMainSS.class);
    ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    ss.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(ss);
    finish();
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("ⓘ Exit ! " + getString(R.string.app_name));
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<p style='text-align:center;'>Please Fill the required details</p><h3 style='text-align:center;'>Click Yes to Exit !</h4>"))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            moveTaskToBack(true);
                            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                            System.exit(0);

                        }
                    })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}

}
```

Comment: @MLN call next activity intent in onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: Thanks @user2025187 But here its not waiting Its moving to next activity without permissions I want ot Stop his can you suggest me without permission dont move to next activity... Your answer seems good but my Issues still same

Comment: I have updated your example that all no new code nothing just replaced my entire code with your code,,, But still its moving to next activity... without giving all permissions.... even one permission also,, its moving I am seeing but when I try to touch its mobing to next activity not staying over there...

Comment: post your updated code so it will help me to solve your porblem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137621/discussion-between-mln-and-user2025187).

Answer (score 1):

```
final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 111;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
      if (!checkReadContactPermission() ||!checkReadPhoneStatePermission()
          || !checkWriteExternalStorage() || !checkReadExternalStorage() ||
          !checkSystemAlertWindowPermission() || !checkWriteContactPermission()) {
                   requestPermission();
            } else {
                  // Move to main act
          }
      } else {
                  // Move to main act
   }
```

**You have to make method for check permission for each**

for ex. this is for READ CONTACT, same way add all other

```
private boolean checkReadContactPermission() {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**Method for request permissions**

```
private void requestPermission() {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                           /* Manifest.permission.CAMERA,*/
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
```

finally RequestPermissionResult

```
   @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                // if granted then 0 else -1
                // i have 5 permisson to check so 0,1,2,3,4..
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[4] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // means all permission are granted..move to Main activity

                } else {
                   // show alert
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you request for permission(s) you'll receive results in `onRequestPermissionsResult` handle results from inside as google docs says [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

**Updated**

The permissions you mentioned are grouped ones example

`Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
 Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

it will ask only one permission for that and one will be for calls(Reading phone state) and you don't need to ask for permission for accessing network state and internet